# Activity members are null after scanning bar-code using ZXing

Tags: java, android, barcode

I want to scan a sequence of bar codes and store in a list. When I try to scan it successfully scan the bar code and call the onActivityResult method. But in onActivityResult method all the Activity class members are null. please help me to fix error.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes and close votes? IMHO this is a perfectly reasonable Android question. Sounds like the downvoters and close voters aren't experienced Android programmers :-(

Answer (score 2):

The Activity is probably being destroyed and re-created again for allocate memory.
Trying using "onSaveInstanceState" to save your attributes.

Comment: How can I restore the attributes in onActivityResult method?

Comment: You don't. If your process is killed due to resource constraints while trying to process the bar code, Android will create a new process and recreate your Actvity before calling `onActivityResult()`. You need to make sure that you restore the state from the Bundle you get in `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that when I click on "save" button of the camera the activity call change orientation method and it will destroy and recreated. try to set

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

it prevent to destroy activity,it work for me.

Comment: This may work for you, but is really not the correct way to solve the problem.